# Python: How to split a dictionary value in float number

Tags: python

My text file looks like so: **comp_339,9.93/10**
I want to extract just rating point as a float value. I couldn't solve this with 'if' statement.
Is there any simple solution for this?

```
d2 = {}
with open('ra.txt', 'r') as r:
    for line in r:
        s = line.strip().split(',')
        d2[s[0]] = "".join(s[1:])
print(d2)
```

Comment: `"comp_339,9.93/10".strip().split(',')[1].split('/')[0]` will give you just the float value

Comment: Please include more sample data

Comment: Also how is your approach already not simple enough?

Comment: is it a CSV file?

Comment: It's a text file and solution must be so {"comp_339":  "9.93"}. My solution didn't return a value so I didn't want to add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
with open('ra.txt', 'r') as r:
    for line in r:
        s = line.strip().split(',')
        rating, _ = s[1].split("/", 1)
        print(rating)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a simple regular expression:

```
import re

line = "comp_339,9.93/10"

before, rating, highscore = re.split(r'[/,]+', line)
print(rating)
```

Which yields

```
9.93
```

Answer (score 0):

First you split the `line` string into `"comp399"` and `"9.93/10"`
then you keep the latter and split it again with `"/"` and keep the first part and convert to float.

```
line = "comp_339,9.93/10"
s = float(line.split()[1].split('/')[0])
# output: 9.93
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code

```
ratings={}
with open('ra.txt' , 'r') as f:
    for l in f.readlines():
        if len(l):
            c, r= ratings.split(',')
            ratings[c.strip()]=float(r.strip().split('/')[0].strip())
```